# Multiple SQL INSERT and UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I'm trying to create a form that enters information into two tables.  In the table1 I'd like to enter the contact's information. In the table2 enter their comment.

Then I want to update the table2 with the id that was generated with the insert into table1.  The form is breaking on the insert into table2.  I tested out the SQL and it worked for the second table insert.

```
    $sql="INSERT INTO table1 (firstname, email, phone) 
          VALUES ('".$Name."','".$Email."', '".$Phone."')";

    $sql.="INSERT INTO table2 (notes_comments, created_date) 
           VALUES ('".$comments."','".$date."')";

    $sql.="UPDATE table2, table1
        SET  table2.notes_quote_id = table1.id
        WHERE table1 = '".$date."'
        AND table2.notes_comments = '".$comments."'
        AND table2.created_date =  table1.created_date";
```

What am I doing wrong?

BELOW is the corrected statement that now works for me:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO table1 (firstname, email, phone) 
      VALUES ('".$yourName."','".$yourEmail."', '".$yourPhone."');";
$sql.="INSERT INTO table2 (notes_comments, created_date) 
      VALUES ('".$comments."','".$datefix."');";
$sql.="UPDATE table2 
      INNER JOIN table1 
      ON table2.created_date = table1.created_date 
      SET table2.notes_quote_id = table1.id 
      WHERE table1.id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table1);";
```

Comment: Multiqueries (if supported by api) should be divided by `;`.

Comment: You are comparing table1 with $date. I think it should be something like table1.date.

Comment: Not a fan of this method because it can be tough to sort what part of a multi query is failing, but yes, queries need to end with ';' so mysql can tell where they end.  
`".$Phone."');";`   
`$date."');";`   
` table1.created_date;";`

Comment: Adding the semicolon worked for the first two insert statements.  The Update didn't work.  @DuaneLortie - Is there another way to insert form data into multiple tables other than running a multi query?

Comment: if you are using mysqli, you could get the insert ID from table1, then your 3rd qry is much easier. After 1st insert,  `$insertID =mysqli_insert_id($link));`  then you can use $insertID for the update rather than a subquery